# Does the background size apply to both images?

Tags: css, background-image

I have a responsive landing page with two background images. **I need both images to have a `background-size` of 40%** but I'm not sure if the way I wrote the CSS the background size is only affecting the first image.

This is my CSS:

```
.section-one {
   background: url(image-here.svg) left bottom no-repeat,
               url(another-image.svg) right bottom no-repeat;
   background-size: 40%;
   padding-bottom: 200px;
}
```

This is how the screen recording's showing the CSS. If you notice, the `40%` is only being applied to the first image:
[image]

Comment: What happened when you tried it? E.g. you could make `url(image-here.svg)` be an invalid URL.

Comment: It looks good in all browsers and devices I tested. However, in user screen recordings, sometimes the only the first image has the correct size.  I'm not sure if this is a recording bug or my css may be failing.

Comment: Oh dear, that sounds awkward to isolate. Are you saying that what appears to the user is correct, but what is recorded is (sometimes) different from what the user sees? Or could it be that the user is using a different browser from you?

Comment: Perhaps the specifications at [The background-size CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) will help to make it more complicated, especially with regard to the notes on SVG.

Comment: It is awkward indeed! Yes, it looks good to me and all devices and browsers I've tested, but in some recordings, it looks wrong. Specially in browsers with 1366 x 600px.

Comment: what do you get when you use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle ? this should the method to trust IMHO :)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Could you explain how to do this? Should I just open the console and type that?

Comment: here is an example  https://jsfiddle.net/jv7n83zm/ ;)

Comment: Thanks. This is what I get after that:

"background-image: none<br> background-size: auto"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the background directive shortcut all the way like this to be sure?

CSS

```
.section-one {
   background: no-repeat left bottom/40%   url('image-here.svg'),
               no-repeat right bottom/40%  url('another-image.svg');
   padding-bottom: 200px;
}
```